# xul services is undefined

Tags: firefox, xul, xpcom

I start my app with `firefox.exe --app application.ini -jsconsole` and the first line of my script is:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

The second line is:

```
alert(typeof services);
```

And it alerts undefined. Nowhere in the documentation does it say how to get the services only that I need gecko 2.

My firefox version is 21.o for Windows but I think the xulrunner that comes with it might be lacking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any module you import will be named exactly as its filename (excluding extension), so in this case you would've to call it `Services` and not `services`. Do not forget that JavaScript variables are case-sensitive.